# In MySQL, how would I duplicate an existing record in a table and a supporting table that relies on the parent table ID?

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

Let's say I have a table of `core` and 2 supporting tables we'll call `activity` and `steps`.

**Core** might contain the following:

```
coreID(int) | coreLabel(varchar)
--------------------------------
1           | Wash Car
12          | Wash Dog
15          | Vacuum the carpet
```

**Activity** might contain the following:

```
aID(int auto) | coreID(int fk) | menuID(int fk)
-----------------------------------------------
1             | 1              | 268
2             | 1              | 269
3             | 12             | 269
4             | 12             | 239
5             | 12             | 230
6             | 15             | 237
7             | 15             | 269
8             | 15             | 244
9             | 15             | 242
```

**Steps** might contain the following:

```
stepID(int auto) | coreID(int fk) | aID(int fk)
-----------------------------------------------
1                | 1              | 1
2                | 1              | 2
3                | 12             | 5
4                | 12             | 6
5                | 12             | 9
6                | 15             | 10
7                | 15             | 11
8                | 15             | 26
```

The website will show the core items. The user should be able to click a button to duplicate an item (e.g. duplicate wash dog, coreID=2) such that **Core** would now have the values

```
coreID(int) | coreLabel(varchar)
--------------------------------
1           | Wash Car
12          | Wash Dog
15          | Vacuum the carpet
16           | Wash Dog (copy)
```

...and the data in **Activity** *should* look like this:

```
aID(int auto) | coreID(int fk) | menuID(int fk)
-----------------------------------------------
1             | 1              | 268
2             | 1              | 269
3             | 12             | 269
4             | 12             | 239
5             | 12             | 230
6             | 15             | 237
7             | 15             | 269
8             | 15             | 244
9             | 15             | 242
10            | 16             | 268
11            | 16             | 269
```

...and then **Steps** *should* look like this:

```
stepID(int auto) | coreID(int fk) | aID(int fk)
-----------------------------------------------
1                | 1              | 1
2                | 1              | 2
3                | 12             | 5
4                | 12             | 6
5                | 12             | 9
6                | 15             | 10
7                | 15             | 11
8                | 15             | 26
9                | 16             | 10
10               | 16             | 11
```

Duplicating the records in **Core** and **Activity** is straight forward, I have no issues there. What I don't know how to do is duplicate the supporting records in **Steps** because when a record is inserted into **Activity**, the inserted value for `aID` is required for the insertion into **Steps** and that specifically is where my dilemma is... Can MySQL handle this for me with a trigger such as what I found here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37470/cascading-inserts-in-mysql and if so, how would I pass in non default values?

**Update**
A trigger on the table isn't going to work. I need to be able to add data to the `Activity` table without the db also adding a row into the `step` table. Normally I think that solution would have worked but not under this scenario.

**Update #2**
I created a [database fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4dbcca/1). This is made up sample data derived from my true source data but has been simplified so hopefully the sample data is sufficient.

```
CREATE TABLE `core` (
    `coreID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `coreLabel` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Untitled',
    PRIMARY KEY (`coreID`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;

CREATE TABLE `activity` (
    `aID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `coreID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `menuID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`aID`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;

CREATE TABLE `steps` (
    `stepID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `coreID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `aID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`stepID`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;

insert into core (corelabel) values ('Wash Car');
insert into core (corelabel) values ('Wash Dog');
insert into core (corelabel) values ('Vacuum Rug');

insert into activity (coreID, menuID) values (1,268);
insert into activity (coreID, menuID) values (1,269);
insert into activity (coreID, menuID) values (12,268);
insert into activity (coreID, menuID) values (12,239);
insert into activity (coreID, menuID) values (12,230);
insert into activity (coreID, menuID) values (15,237);
insert into activity (coreID, menuID) values (15,269);
insert into activity (coreID, menuID) values (15,244);
insert into activity (coreID, menuID) values (15,242);
insert into activity (coreID, menuID) values (4,268);


insert into steps (coreID, aID) values (1,1);
insert into steps (coreID, aID) values (1,2);
insert into steps (coreID, aID) values (12,5);
insert into steps (coreID, aID) values (12,6);
insert into steps (coreID, aID) values (12,9);
insert into steps (coreID, aID) values (15,10);
insert into steps (coreID, aID) values (15,11);
insert into steps (coreID, aID) values (15,26);

select * from core;
select * from activity;
select * from steps;
Select
    c.coreID,
    c.coreLabel,
    a.aID,
    a.menuID,
    s.stepID
From
    core c Left Join
    activity a On a.coreID = c.coreID Left Join
    steps s On s.aID = a.aID;
```

-- If we pretend a button was clicked to duplicate "Wash Car", we'd expect the following inserts to occur;
-- the issue is actually getting these values programmatically;

```
insert into core (corelabel) values ('Wash Car (copy)');
insert into activity (coreID, menuID) values (4,269);   
insert into steps (coreID, aID) values (4,10);
insert into steps (coreID, aID) values (4,11);

Select
    c.coreID,
    c.coreLabel,
    a.aID,
    a.menuID,
    s.stepID
From
    core c Left Join
    activity a On a.coreID = c.coreID Left Join
    steps s On s.aID = a.aID;
```

The last select query (see above) returns 4 records. This should be correct since "Wash Car" has two steps. The scenario is that the user wants to use the "Wash Car" as a template for another procedure. After clicking the duplicate button next to "Wash Car" on the web site, we should see 6 records returned and we should see an entry for "Wash Car (copy)"

Comment: Yes, it wiill. ```CREATE TRIGGER steps_ti AFTER INSERT ON `Activity` FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO Steps (coreID,aID) VALUES (NEW.aID,NEW.coreID);```

Comment: @JimishGamit I tried the NEW.coreID in a trigger and it did not keep the expected coreID. In the Steps table, I expected to see `4` and instead inserted `16`.

Comment: Why would you want to duplicate data?

Comment: "e.g. duplicate wash dog, coreID=2" - It's 12 in your first table. Please fix your sample data.

Comment: @Strawberry The scenario is so the user can make a "template" and them modify the template instead of having to create the entire process from scratch every time.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel nice catch! Sample data corrected.

Comment: it giving you correct data`15 Vacuum the carpet` in `core` table which I believe is a last record. so new entry will have `16`

Comment: OK. Fair enough!

Comment: @JimishGamit You may be correct. Let me look closer at the values in my database.

Comment: Fixed some other sample data inconsistencies.

Comment: Sample data still doesn't match. Also - what is the point of the `steps` table? It seems to be a copy of `activity` table just without `menuID`.

Comment: The `activity` and `steps` table was trimmed down for the SO question. The key values match. The `wash dog` originally was entered as 4 but that didn't make sense. The next value would have been 16 so I updated the other tables to reflect the 16 instead of the 4.

Comment: OIC, I did not include all the `aid` values that are referenced in the `steps` table. Is that what you are referring too?

Comment: You've copied only two of three rows. And the menuIDs don't match. But the main problem I see, is that you've accepted a trigger, which looks suspicious to me. All it does is to (partially) copy data from a new row in `activity` into a new row in `steps`. And it will always copy the data, when you insert something into `activity` - Not only, when you want to duplicate an item. However, there is no information in your question that you want that. My point is: The trigger is doing more than you asked for in your post.

Comment: OMG, you are right about the trigger! That is not the desired outcome. I should have tested more thoroughly before accepting.

Comment: I found a dbfiddle.uk but not sure how to use it. I'll see if I can figure it out and maybe that will help clarify the dataset and the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Duplicating the records in Core and Activity is straight forward

And would probably look something like this:

```
set @sourceCoreID = 12;

insert into core (coreLabel)
  select coreLabel
  from core
  where coreID = @sourceCoreID;

set @newCoreID = last_insert_id();

insert into activity (coreID, menuID)
  select @newCoreID, menuID
  from activity
  where coreID = @sourceCoreID;
```

All you need now, is to copy some data from the new `activity` rows to `steps` (At least it looks like that in your sample result). And there is not much magic needed:

```
insert into steps(coreID, aID)
  select coreID, aID
  from activity
  where coreID = @newCoreID;
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vhAX1VvA47WRVNSx11RmqQ/0)

Comment: I think you are on the right approach but this needs some tweaking. When the new activity is created in the `activity` table, it should gets a new value for the aID. The aID is an auto increment int datatype. It is the pk for `activity` and the fk in `steps`. It's a one-to-many relationship. The newly copied steps would take this value instead of the existing value that is there for the source coreID.

Comment: `insert into activity (coreID, menuID)` - I don't set `aID` - so it gets an auto_increment value.

Comment: Good morning. The auto_increment is okay on the `activity` table but whatever value is generated for the aID in the activity becomes the FK for the `step.aID` (in order to build the relationship). The `insert into steps(coreID, aID) select coreID, aID from activity where coreID = @newCoreID` doesn't retain the aID needed for the steps table.

Comment: Sorry, but the query is doing exactly what you say. It copies newly generated aIDs from `activities` into `steps`. Look again at the result in the fiddle. New aIDs generated in `activities` are (10,11,12). New aIDs inserted into `steps` are (10,11,12). If that's not what you want, then I don't undestand your question at all.

Comment: You are 100% correct with your solution. I had a stray insert in *my fiddle* that was inserting bad data. (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻  I thought it was coming from the `insert` query. I am so sorry and I appreciate you sticking with me on this.

Comment: Just a quick follow up, the solution/technique provided by Paul is working beautifully. I was severely over engineering and over thinking this. It should have donged on me sooner that what I was trying to do wasn't as complicated as I was making it but Paul stuck with me. Many wouldn't have.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER steps_ti 
AFTER INSERT ON `Activity` 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO Steps (aID,coreID) VALUES (NEW.aID,NEW.coreID);
```

Comment: I've never needed to use a trigger before so this is new to me; thus, I don't understand why this works. That is beyond the scope of this question and a new topic for me to go read. I've marked it as correct as it seems to be doing exactly what I was looking for. I assume if I need to "pass" in more values, I just include it on the insert statement.

Comment: Yes. You can add those into `insert` statement

Comment: I had to unaccept this as the answer. Paul made a comment about the trigger doing more than intended and was correct. I need more control over when the insert occurs and the trigger doesn't seem to allow for that flexibility.