# MySQL INSERT INTO... SELECT multiple values from destination table and using it as part of the insert into the same destination table

Tags: mysql

This SO post is a follow up question to my SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56547617/in-mysql-how-would-i-duplicate-an-existing-record-in-a-table-and-a-supporting-t/56550641#56550641). I created a new post since the original question was answered and did not want to distract from answer. In experimenting with the previous solution, it got me thinking and thus this SO question was born.

Reference: [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vhAX1VvA47WRVNSx11RmqQ/1) where I'm performing an *INSERT INTO with Select* in MySQL. In playing around with the data, is it possible to grab some data from the destination table matching a PK field (coreID = :org_coreID) and then combining that with a select statement to perform an *INSERT INTO with Select* using a :new_coreID?

**I know this SQL is invalid** but I'm hoping the statement below will help explain the data columns I need to insert into the `steps` table.

```
INSERT INTO steps(coreid, wolid, venueID,aid, tcount, rCount, pMax, groupID)
SELECT
    a.coreID,
    IFNULL(s.woLID, 0) as woLID,
    s.venueID,
    a.aID,
    (select tCount, rCount, pMax, groupID from steps where coreID = :orig_coreID)
FROM
    activity a Left Join
    step s On s.aID = a.aID
WHERE
    a.coreID = :new_coreID;
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Updated the query; part of it didn't paste right and got lost during the formatting.

Comment: From what it looks like, that you're trying to select the row your insert would create, no; but you might want to look into BEFORE INSERT triggers. _Also, you cannot have a subquery that returns multiple fields or multiple rows in a SELECT expression._

Comment: I didn’t think it was possible but thought I’d double check. I’ll look into *BEFORE INSERT* trigger. I’m aware of them but have never had a use case for it so this will be an interesting experiment.